# object not iterable when implementing transformers for a pipeline in skit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a list of strings which I watn to classify. I'm using a pipeline object.

I implemented two dummies transformers: one convert the data to an specific format (to be accepted by another transformer) and the other converts the data again to its original form (a kind of inverse).

X and y are list of strings, suppose `X=['London is great', 'London is beautiful', 'I hate London']` and `y=['p','p','n']`. I want `X` to be converted to a list of lists of strings: `X=[['London is great'], ['London is beautiful'], ['I hate London']]`

My code is the following:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator


vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input=u'content',
                             analyzer=u'word',
                             lowercase=True,
                             stop_words=cached_stopwords,
                             strip_accents=u'unicode',
                             ngram_range=(1, 3), binary=False)

estimators = [('pre_ds', PreprocessPreDS()),
              ('post_ds', PreprocesarPostDS()),
              ('vectorizer', vectorizer),
              ('feature_selector', SelectKBest(chi2, k=100)),
              ('clf', MultinomialNB())]  
# create the pipeline
pipe = Pipeline(estimators)
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

where my costume transformers are the following:

```
class PreprocessPreDS(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def transform(self, X, *_):
        return [[x] for x in X]

    def fit(self, *_):
        return self

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self.fit(X)

    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        """
        :param deep: ignored, as suggested by scikit learn's documentation
        :return: dict containing each parameter from the model as name and its current value
        """
        return {}

    def set_params(self, **parameters):
        """
        set all parameters for current objects
        :param parameters: dict containing its keys and values to be initialised
        :return: self
        """
        for parameter, value in parameters.items():
            setattr(self, parameter, value)
        return self


class PreprocesarPostDS(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def transform(self, X, *_):
        return [x[0] for x in X]

    def fit(self, *_):
        return self

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self.fit(X)

    def get_params(self, deep=True):
        """
        :param deep: ignored, as suggested by scikit learn's documentation
        :return: dict containing each parameter from the model as name and its current value
        """
        return {}

    def set_params(self, **parameters):
        """
        set all parameters for current objects
        :param parameters: dict containing its keys and values to be initialised
        :return: self
        """
        for parameter, value in parameters.items():
            setattr(self, parameter, value)
        return self
```

When I ran this code, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rodrigo/nb/train_nb_pipeline.py", line 449, in <module>
    process(args.label, args.evaluate, args.label_all, corpus=args.corpus_path)
  File "/home/rodrigo/nb/train_nb_pipeline.py", line 179, in process
    pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/home/rodrigo/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 248, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/home/rodrigo/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 213, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name])
  File "/home/rodrigo/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/memory.py", line 362, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rodrigo/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 581, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/home/rodrigo/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 869, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "/home/rodrigo/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 790, in _count_vocab
    for doc in raw_documents:
TypeError: 'PreprocessPostDS' object is not iterable
```

However, if I exclude `('pre_ds', PreprocessPreDS())` and `('post_ds', PreprocesarPostDS())` from `estimators`, it runs all rigth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    return self.fit(X)
```

to:

```
def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    return self.fit(X).transform(X)
```

In the above code, you are essentially returning the `self`. `self` is the class object (PreprocessPreDS and PreprocessPostDS in this case). `fit_transform()` should return the transformed data, not class objects.